# My Application Crashing when using url connections

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am working on sever based project in that if i am push to 3 view controllers one by one .. each view i am requesting urls and i am getting data from the sever in this scenario it working fine but when i pop (or) coming back to previous view click in back button continuously my app crashing because the data from server not received completely and again i am requesting another url

```
 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    [self hideLoader];

    if (_delegate != nil) {

        NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc]initWithData:responseData];

        [_delegate finishedReceivingData:data withRequestMessage:requestMessage];

        [data release];

    } -- getting error here..
```

and also i want crash report for my application is there any frameworks?

Comment: Do you have anything about that crash? log in the debugger(cmd+Y) or from Debug Navigation(cmd+5)?

Comment: any other solution for this because i am using the same delegate for through out application and also for all url request

Comment: I dont use ARC too, but the shortcut's are the same. the whole idea is to give us more knowledge of the error, message or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

In the dealloc method of the controller/view (depends who is your delegate) you need to nil your delegate property.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
   _urlConnection.delegate = nil;

[super dealloc];
}
```

Don't count on the nil condition.
It can be deallocated, but not nil.

Comment: any other solution for this because i am using the same delegate for through out application and also for all url request